# How to add a custom button to a page using bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have following code using which I am trying to add a facebook icon button to my page. But, I am unable to see that image bg in my page.

```
<button class="facebook"></button>
```

My css :

```
.facebook{  
    background: url('../img/fb.jpg') no-repeat   
}
```

I have included the css file in my html pg too:

```
 <link href="../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using bootstrap 3 you have something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">My button</button>
```

If you want to add some background to that button, add your class:

```
<button type="button" class="btn facebook">My button</button>
```

Be sure that you first add bootstrap css to your page and then your custom css because the last css overrides previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your custom class to your button input.

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="facebook">
```

o so you are using fontawesome... correct ..

```
 <linkbutton class="myclass"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> fa-facebook</linkbutton >
```

This is what i do in my asp.net

Answer (score 0):

may be you are missing  ';' in css code

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap, you can use fontawesome icons for your buttons using the cdn or downloading the glyphicons

```
           <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
              <button class="facebook" ><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>facebook</button> 

         In you code you could have missed the correct link to your css file. Check the absolute or relative links to the css file. 

         <link href="../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

You also missed the semi colon in

```
              background: url('../img/fb.jpg') no-repeat
```

Comment: oh yeah, like Vladislav said you can add the class="btn" as well to improve the styling.